# Python get functions from module and display them on OptionMenu

Tags: python, tkinter

Hello I'm trying to make a program where it asks for a python module, get its functions, append them into a list, and put the list values as options for a OptionMenu. I have the following code:

```
def fetch_module():
    global get_module
    global functionmodulename
    get_module = askopenfilename(title="get module", filetypes=[("Python source","*.py")])
    functionmodulename = inspect.getmodulename(get_function)
    getfunctions(sys.modules[get_module])
def fetch_function(module)
    global l
    l = []
    for key, value in module.__dict__.items():
        if type(value) is FunctionType:
            l.append(value)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    function_name = StringVar
    OptionMenu(function_name, l).pack()
    fetch_module()
    mainloop()
```

However, if I run this, a "[]"show up as the only choice. can I fix this?

Comment: Could you please show your actual code.  That one doesn't even compile.  And it uses lots of undefined names.  Not just due to missing imports I think.

Comment: Uthis is part of my original source, and my original source is 2000 lines long, can I post it? I will edit the parts with unknown names

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that not all 2k lines of code are needed to get the function names of a module and display them in an `OptionMenu`.  So please take the source code and narrow it down to a minimal, but _runnable_ piece of code which shows the problem.  Is getting the function names a problem at all?  Have you tested the single steps individually without the rest of the program? Was that even possible?  Because from what you have shown, you did not use ”real” functions but `def` just as a way to label code to jump to and lots of globals.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to fix in your code. First of all, you need to create the Tkinter app, let's call it master.

Right now you are assigning the class StringVar to the variable function_name. That does not work. You need to create a new StringVar instance.

Putting a list of things in an OptionMenu is also tricky. see: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/optionmenu.htm

```
import Tkinter                                                                                                                   
# or depending on your python version: import tkinter                                                                            

if __name__ == "__main__":                                                                                                       
    master = Tkinter.Tk()                                                                                                        
    sv = Tkinter.StringVar(master)                                                                                               
    l = ['a','b','b','c']                                                                                                        
    apply( Tkinter.OptionMenu, (master, sv) + tuple(l)).pack()                                                                   
    Tkinter.mainloop()
```